# Secondary Work on Kant's Critique of Pure Reason

Tags: kant, heidegger, critique-of-pure-reason

I'm currently reading through the Critique of Pure Reason for the first time and have on hand a book by Martin Heidegger titled, "Phenomenological Interpretations of Kant's Critique of Pure Reason." I was wondering if I should use this as a supplementary work to the Critique, tackle it alone, or use another secondary source for better understanding. So far I'm not having any real trouble with the work, but I assume that I'll probably need some help eventually.

TL;DR: I'm wondering if Heidegger's commentaries on Kant's Critique are a good supplement for a first time reading of the Critique.

Comment: The Heidegger work I am unfamiliar with. But let me recommend the Routledge guidebook to the Critique of Pure Reason.

Comment: Maybe useful [Cambridge Companions and Intro](https://www.google.com/search?rlz=1C1GCEB_enIT869IT869&biw=1422&bih=678&tbm=bks&ei=ug5NXsmrOqzCmwWwxLbQCw&q=cambridge+introduction+to+kant%27s+critique&oq=cambridge+introduction+to+kant%27s+critique&gs_l=psy-ab.3...1679.3902.0.4173.12.10.0.0.0.0.425.1120.0j2j0j1j1.4.0....0...1c.1.64.psy-ab..10.0.0....0.yh0FNonTiSY)

Comment: Also Karl Ameriks' [Interpreting Kant's Critiques (2003)](https://books.google.it/books?id=Bea04nWdCF4C&printsec=frontcover).

Comment: I've not read it, but IMO Heidegger's book may be too much "theory- (Heidegger's) laden"

Comment: I agree that Heidegger's "commentaries" on other authors are more about Heidegger than the material. He heavily distorts the meaning of a text whenever it suits his own agenda. So, not exactly a good companion of one wants to understand Kant.

Comment: I'm about to start reading the *Critique of Pure Reason*. I'm very well read on Heidegger and I had a similar idea. But just a fair warning about Heidegger in general (if anyone reads this), a lot of his courses on other authors are more about him and how he uses concepts differently from those authors (with the exception of the Pre-Socratics). So I'm not holding out hope. In a month or two I'll update on it.

Answer (score 1):

Heidegger is usually a good Kant scholar unless you're interested in Kant's philosophy of natural science (which is very significant but doesn't exhaust the whole). He usually speaks a lot (indirectly) about the difference between Kant and neo-Kantians and German Idealists, both of whom pursue the more logically-minded part of Kant's work and give up Kant's notion of dependence of thought on intuition. I think he's a reliable source but, of course, you don't have to agree with Heidegger that these elements in Kant's work which Heidegger finds most important for his own thought. It's interesting to contrast Kant with Fichte, Hegel etc.